# OpenCV python videowriter Windows output mp4/other web video

Tags: python, opencv, video, html5-video, mp4

I am trying to use OpenCV in python to output videos that can be used with the HTML5 video tag. However, I can only find things that output avi files, which doesn't work with the video tag Does anyone know any compatible FOUR_CCs that output mp4 files?

Comment: Have you tried x264? If so, where does the problem lie exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You should take at look at [this link](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php). It lists all FOUR_CC for any output format.